# Create Double line Border in table

Tags: tables, formatting, rules

Here, i have simple latex code which generate simple table. However, i want double lined border in my table. How can i generate that?

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
x & x & x \\ \hline
x & x & x \\ \hline
x & x & x \\ \hline
x & x & x \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Please help me out.

I want table like below,

[image]

Comment: Please do mind that a table typeset like that is kind of a typographical horror. I would advise to present it better. Perhaps reading `booktabs` documentation. But see the answer if you still want to do it that way

Answer (score 3):

Since both frames are using thicker lines than the normal table lines, two nested `\fbox` commands solves the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{\doublerulesep}
\fbox{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
    x & x & x \\ \hline
    x & x & x \\ \hline
    x & x & x \\ \hline
    x & x & x \\
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

For nicer tables, see ilFuria's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361188/create-double-line-border-in-table/361192#comment890443_361188).

Answer (score 2):

Insert the table inside a `\fbox`. Although I think you should read [`booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) introduction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
x & x & x \\ \hline
x & x & x \\ \hline
x & x & x \\ \hline
x & x & x \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `hhline`, and `caption` to have a decent vertical spacing between caption and table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption, hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
  %\fbox{
  \begin{tabular}{||l|l|l||}
    \hhline{t|:===t:|}
    x & x & x \\ \hhline{||---||}
    x & x & x \\ \hhline{||---||}
    x & x & x \\ \hhline{||---||}
    x & x & x \\
    \hhline{b|:===b:|}
  \end{tabular}%}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `\fbox` or package `hhline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{||l|l|l||}\hhline{|t:=:=:=:t|}
    x & x & x \\ \hhline{||-|-|-||}
    x & x & x \\ \hhline{||-|-|-||}
    x & x & x \\ \hhline{||-|-|-||}
    x & x & x \\ \hhline{|b:=:=:=:b|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @herbert...Thanks a lot. You solved my problem..